# Viewbox and border

Tags: xaml, store

I am writing a Store app with XAML and C#. I want to use Border and ViewBox. I got border styled, so I do not have to set properties that many times. I set BorderThickness to 2, and color to White, but this causes problems in my Viewbox.

Here it is in XAML:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform">
  <Grid Width="600" Height="600">
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
      </Style>
      <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
          <Border>
            <Viewbox>
              <TextBlock Text="T" />
            </Viewbox>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
```

The result of this is:

[image]

The problem is the scaled border around the letter "T".

I do not want to remove above styling for Border in Grid.Resources. I found only one solution so far...

```
            <Viewbox>
              <Viewbox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Style>
              </Viewbox.Resources>
              <TextBlock Text="T" />
```

... what would give correct result:

[image]

, but I do not want to put these lines after each ViewBoxes, because there will be many.
I also tried to make a component, what has this default "resource" of zero thick border, but that had bad scaling.

**So my question is** how to to remove that border?

Answer (score 0):

You're right to use the zero value for BorderThickness. There just might be another element in the visual tree hierarchy that also holds a default value that causes this.

I can't test this right now, but I can recommend this tool to you:
http://blois.us/Snoop/

You can inspect the visual tree with this by dragging the crosshair above your running debug application. Every time I stumbled upon a problem like this I found it highly useful to see which controls really appear at runtime, because with xaml it can be really tough to know it all. Hope you can find it!