# How to remove "focused" border from XAML listbox?

Tags: xaml, listbox, microsoft-metro

This problem is about the listbox itself and not it's cells. If I put listbox into a viewbox, and click on an item, the whole listbox will be surrounded with a 1px border. I do not want that, because it is ugly. How to remove this border?

Details:

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
        <Grid Width="200">
          <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Rajzelemek}" Background="{x:Null}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <ContentControl Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Content="{Binding Ikonja}" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          </ListBox>
        </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
  </Grid>
```

If I comment the `<Viewbox Grid.Row....` part, everything is fine, but not scaled. I want stuff to get scaled, well that is why I use the viewbox, but I do not want this border:

[image]

The code above was put on a metro BlankPage1 too, and made the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for what's in the `ListBoxItem` template wherein there's a `Rectangle` acting as a Focus Visual, if you check out the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709919.aspx) you'll see it with a default brush attributed to it (FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush) which you could either change in the template, or provide your own resource for it to find before it hits the default dictionaries like;

```
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Sorry I was going by the picture you have, thought it was the item. In any case since your `ViewBox` is the culprit you just need to interact with the `Border` control within it >[like you showed in a previous post of your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380119/viewbox-and-border)< where you're the one making that border. Something like;

```
<Viewbox>
              <Viewbox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Style>
              </Viewbox.Resources>

...

</ViewBox>
```

Comment: Not the listbox item, but the listbox itself has a border (around all of the items, and the items have no border). I could not solve my issue with this info; may I ask you for a bit more detail?

Comment: @Zéiksz see edited answer, sorry was just going by your screenshot picture and didn't read the part about the `ViewBox`

Comment: The answer is totally logical, and "should work", but does not. I have no idea if it works as should under WPF, but with metro there is still a border inside the listbox - only if listbox or one of it's listitem is focused. I even tried this "targettype-border" thing under the listbox resources - no luck so far.

Comment: Yes, but I need that for UI scaling. I just checked GridView, what has no border. My guess, that if that thing is really a Border, that would scale too.